# JQUERY - Custom HTML Option Data for IF Statement for Chained Selection

Tags: html, jquery, if-statement

edit: see "Edit" Section for updated question

I am trying to make the second dropdown selection dependent of the first, using jquery.

- get "data-type" of first selection
- if "data-type" == "String" trigger filter change of second selections "data-foo" containing value N

HTML Selections

```html
<select id="first" name="first-selection" class="form-control">
 <option value="a" class="b" data-type="c">a</option>
</select>

<select id="second" name="second" class="form-control">
 <option value="n" data-foo="m">n</option>
</select>
```

I used to following code to check if I am able to get the "data-type" value and display it. But any attempt to get the data for an if statement failed so far.

```js
$('#first').change(function () {
 var selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
 $('#type').html(selected.data('type'));
 }).change();
```

edit - code with if statement

- how do I use "data-type" for an if statement?

### EDIT

New code and [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k5vs1e4m/1/) to make myself clear

```html
<select id="first" name="first-selection" class="form-control">
<option value="1" class="type1" data-type="snowboot">bli</option>
<option value="2" class="type2" data-type="nose">bla</option>
<option value="3" class="type3" data-type="head">blu</option>
</select>

<p>Test output: <span id="type"></span>.</p>

<select id="second" name="second-selection" class="form-control">
<option value="11"  data-foo="green">one of three</option>
<option value="22"  data-foo="red">two of three</option>
<option value="33"  data-foo="red">three of three</option>
</select>
```

```js
$(function(){

    $('#first').change(function(){
        var selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
        
       $('#type').html(selected.data('type')); 
       

    }).change();
});
```

**Question**

How do I use "data-type" and put it as an if statement before the function? The following won't do anything

```js
if ($('select[id=first] option').filter(':selected').type() == "nose")
```

```
if(selected.data('type') == "nose")
```

```
var myvar = $('#first option:selected').data();
if(myvar == 'nose')
```

This is the code I want to run after the if statement:

```js
var $firstvar= $("#first");
$secondvar= $("#second");

$options = $secondvar.find('option')
            $firstvar.on('change', function () {
                $secondvar.html($options.filter('[data-foo="' + 'red' + '"]'));
            }).trigger('change');
```

Comment: You mention an `if()` in subject but none shown in code. It's both unclear what you are trying to accomplish and what the specific problem is. You need to explain all this with more specifics. Also what is `$('#type')` and what does setting it's html have to do with the other select?

Comment: i've edited my OP and hope it is not confusing anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you want. It will check, whether the selected option of the first select was of any of the types mentioned in the object `conditions` and will then go through all options of the second select and either show or hide them (using the jQuery `.toggle(.toggle(!isNose||this.dataset.foo==="red"))` method). The expression `show=!found||this.dataset.foo===found` will evaluate to `true` for all cases where `found` is `undefined` and to `false` only if `found` is "trueish" AND `this.dataset.foo===found` is false.

```js
$(function() {
  const conditions={nose:"red",head:"green"}; // add as many as you like ...
  $('#first').change(function() {
    let show,first=true; // first makes sure only ONE option can be set
    const found=conditions[ $(this).find(":selected").data("type") ];
    $('#second option').each(function(){
      $(this).toggle(show=!found||this.dataset.foo===found);
      if(first&&show) first=!(this.selected=true); // select first visible option
    })
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="first" name="first-selection" class="form-control">
  <option value="1" class="type1" data-type="snowboot">bli</option>
  <option value="2" class="type2" data-type="nose">bla</option>
  <option value="3" class="type3" data-type="head">blu</option>
</select>

<p>Test output: <span id="type"></span>.</p>

<select id="second" name="second-selection" class="form-control">
  <option value="11" data-foo="green">one of three</option>
  <option value="22" data-foo="red">two of three</option>
  <option value="33" data-foo="red">three of three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. this works perfectly but I still have the issue with an if statement as I am going to check on multiple strings ("nose", "head", ...)

Comment: Ah, you want to be able to enforce several show/hide rules based on different selections of the first select. Is that what you have in mind?

Comment: wow, perfect. thanks a lot! grüße nach hannover